# Is it good practice to create an object by using the same object in order to access the dot notation feature?

Tags: swift, oop, struct, datamodel

```
let tipAM1 = Tip(title: "Gym 1 Title", body: "body text, yada, yada, yada." , sourceName: "SourceName", sourceURL: "www.test.com", sponsorLogo: "TBD", sponsorURL: "www.test.com")
let tipAM2 = Tip(title: "Gym 2 Title", body: "body text, yada, yada, yada." , sourceName: "SourceName", sourceURL: "www.test.com", sponsorLogo: "TBD", sponsorURL: "www.test.com")
let tipAM3 = Tip(title: "Gym 3 Title", body: "body text, yada, yada, yada." , sourceName: "SourceName", sourceURL: "www.test.com", sponsorLogo: "TBD", sponsorURL: "www.test.com")
let tipAM4 = Tip(title: "Gym 4 Title", body: "body text, yada, yada, yada." , sourceName: "SourceName", sourceURL: "www.test.com", sponsorLogo: "TBD", sponsorURL: "www.test.com")

var tipArray0 = [tipAM1, tipAM2, tipAM3, tipAM4]

let topic0 = Topic(title: "Exercise", icon: "Gym", tipArray: tipArray0)
```

// QUESTION: Selected data to display in when user taps UIButton (Should I create a new/different struct that allows me use dot notation.  Currently, I'm creating a Topic object with a Topic object)?

```
let button1 = Topic(title: topic0.title, icon: topic0.icon, tipArray: topic0.tip)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob for editing my verbose original post!  I think I may of answered my own question.  I edited my code in the last line to simply be:  `button1 = topic0`.  It seems to work well b/c I use use dot notation on `topic0`.  Example: `topic0.title`

Comment: If you're trying to create a new `Topic` instance, and if `Topic` is a `struct`, you can just do `let foo = topic0`. No need to create a new one using dot notation for all of the individual properties. I'm unclear why you want to call this new `Topic` instance `button1`, though...